# Nintex Docusign Send document / Retrieve envelope running long time

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Nintex Docusign Send document / Retrieve envelope. Normally once the document is sent i will get the response / handle immediately back. But both with my developer / prod account its taking a long time to run. Is there is any issue in the docusign end?

Comment: Got its resolved using the following post https://community.nintex.com/thread/11029

Answer (score 0):

You can ping the following URL's and see if the Docusign webservices are up.

- DocuSign Production system:
  https://www.docusign.net/restapi/service_information
- DocuSign Demo
  system: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/service_information